# Using a generator

Tags: electrical, generator

Power is out with 100+ temperatures. The window AC has a 615r plug and I cannot find an adapter that will allow me to plug the AC to the generator.
How do I plug it in?

Comment: What model generator do you have, and is it 120V only or 120/240V?

Comment: We are going to need the model of generator, or at least what kind of receptacles it has.

Answer (score 1):

Most portable generators have a few different types of receptacles built in.  Most portable generators offer all, or some combination of the following receptacles.

- NEMA 5-15 (125 volt, 15 ampere)
- NEMA 5-20 (125 volt, 20 ampere)
- NEMA L14-30 (250 volt, 30 ampere)
- NEMA 14-50 (250 volt, 50 ampere)

If you're looking to plug in a device with a NEMA 6-15 plug (250 volt, 15 ampere),  you're likely going to need more than a straight wire adapter. You'll either need a small panel with a 250 volt 15 ampere circuit breaker, or an inline 250 volt 15 ampere breaker.

The A/C unit's cord is only rated for 15 amperes. If you made an adapter to go from NEMA 6-15 to NEMA L14-30, for example. The cord could potentially be exposed to 30 amperes, which could cause it to fail catastrophically.

You need is a circuit breaker between the 30 ampere receptacle, and the 15 ampere plug.  The circuit breaker will protect the A/C unit, and the cord.

Answer (score 0):

In the United States, a NEMA 6-15R receptacle is typically used on Air Conditioners that require 240 Volt AC service (sometimes called "220".) See [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#/media/File:NEMA_simplified_pins.svg) at [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector).

If you have a generator with a 120 Volt AC output (sometimes called "110"), do not attempt to connect a 240-Volt air conditioner, not even using a plug adaptor.  **This could be dangerous, or damage your equipment.**

If your generator has a switch to allow you to select "120 or 240" Volts -- and again, it could be marked "110 or 220" -- then it should be safe to:

- select 220-240 Volts
- make sure your Air Conditioner is rated for 220-240 Volts
- connect the Air Conditioner to the generator, even if an adaptor is required.

You may be able to get an adaptor at your local hardware store/electrical supply/home improvement center, or wire one together from individual parts they can sell you.  If you have any doubts, talk to a qualified electrician.